# How do I make a program in Python Command?

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I just started programming, and while the tutorial I was using had me use IDLE, I wanted to make proper programs in the the command window so that I could use py2exe to make them into .exe's. Unfortunately, upon opening up the command window, it looked nothing like IDLE. I had no idea how to even start making my code, after looking, and finding nothing on the grounds that this is a somewhat basic question, I really need to know the best way to do this, and if I'm not understanding something about py2exe or Python, let me know.

Comment: Use your favourite text editor and create a python script - save it as `<myscript>.py` then you can run this script in the command terminal with `python <myscript.py>`

Comment: If you are beginner download pycharm [Download Link](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/download-thanks.htm). It will help you

Answer (score 0):

Command lines are nothing like IDE, if you want to develop using something similar to a command line, you should try vim or emacs,

sublime and pycharm also allows you to run/compile code and feels more like IDE / text editor,

If you want make exe files py2exe is recommended, you could also start python from batch files(windows)

There is also the gui options like TkInter or QT to make apps

Depending on what applications you need there will be a better option, you asked a question to general to have a silver bullet.